# How to deactivate the HTMl details tag?

Tags: html, angular, tags

I want to make in Angular a new component with "details" selector, how I can deactivate the default details?

Comment: What "default details" are you talking about?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp

Comment: I still don't understand what "default" details...

Comment: you can "simulate" a details tag with a simple *ngIf

Answer (score 0):

There's no need at all to deactivate the `tag` element. If you need to create custom tags take a look at this article https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements.